# Create multifile uploader in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, flash, file-upload

I want to create a multiple file uploader in php with the play, pause, resume, cancel functionality. something like the mediafire project.

Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 3):

I use this one: http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this one](http://weblog.cahlan.com/2006/12/flex-upload-component.html).  Flex based free and open source, for multiple files, with nice UI.

Example probably will not work, 'cos the guy who wrote it block ability to load files to his server, but it was working last year and i use this code in one of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

Play/Pause in the middle of upload? First you need a client side solution for that. Take a look at Yahoo [BrowserPlus](http://developer.yahoo.com/browserplus/)